# c# variable not updating

Tags: timer, xamarin.android, orientation, recording

I'm trying to create a Xamarin Android application, where I record the orientationsensor data. I set a timer that runs for 10 ms, and restarts 400 times.

```
public void rogzit_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)        
        {                                           
            timer1 = new Timer();

            timer1.Interval = 10;
            timer1.Elapsed += Timer1_Elapsed;


            if (OrientationSensor.IsMonitoring)
            {
                rogzit.Enabled = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
                {
                    jel = 1;
                    timer1.Start();

                    while (jel != 0)
                    {

                    }

                }               
                string mappa = Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDocuments).AbsolutePath;
                rogzit.Enabled = true;
                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(mappa, array);
            }                       
        }
        private void Timer1_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {

            timer1.Stop();
            idoo[db] = Convert.ToString(db * 0.01);
            meres[db] = szog.ToString("f2");
            array[db] = string.Format("{0} {1}", idoo[db], meres[db]);
            db += 1;
            jel = 0;
        }
```

The variable `szog` should change, but the it stays the same.

```
public void OrientationSensor_Readingchanged(object sender, OrientationSensorChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            xQ = e.Reading.Orientation.X;
            yQ = e.Reading.Orientation.Y;
            zQ = e.Reading.Orientation.Z;
            wQ = e.Reading.Orientation.W;

            double sinr_cosp = +2.0 * (wQ * xQ + yQ * zQ);
            double cosr_cosp = +1.0 - 2.0 * (xQ * xQ + yQ * yQ);
            xAngle = Math.Atan2(sinr_cosp, cosr_cosp);

            double sinp = +2.0 * (wQ * yQ - zQ * xQ);



            if (Math.Abs(sinp) >= 1)
            {
                if (sinp>0)
                {
                    yAngle = (Math.PI / 2);
                }
                else
                {
                    yAngle = -1 * (Math.PI / 2);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                yAngle = Math.Asin(sinp);
            }

            double siny_cosp = +2.0 * (wQ *zQ + xQ * yQ);
            double cosy_cosp = +1.0 - 2.0 * (yQ * yQ + zQ * zQ);
            zAngle = Math.Atan2(siny_cosp, cosy_cosp);

            double elojel;

            if (xAngle > 0)
            {
                elojel = 1;
            }
            else if (xAngle < 0)
            {
                elojel = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                elojel = 0;
            }

            szog = Math.Sqrt(yAngle * yAngle + xAngle * xAngle)*elojel;
            pf = szog.ToString("f2");
            szogErtek.Text = string.Format("{0} [rad]", pf);
```

In `Orientationsensor_Readingchanged` I give a value to `szog`, that changes accordingly to the orientation. But it stays the same value, as when the `rogzit_Clicked` started, and records that value 400 times.

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint in `Timer1_Elapsed` to see how many times it hit in 4s?

Answer (score 0):

The line `szogErtek.Text = string.Format("{0} [rad]", pf);` does not seem to be called on a UI thread since it's inside an event listener.
You have to move the portion of the task that updates the UI onto the main thread using Activity.RunOnUiThread. So, it has to look something like this:

```
Activity.RunOnUiThread(szogErtek.Text = string.Format("{0} [rad]", pf));
```